# How can I set variable php and mysql code

Tags: php

I want to set a variable "name",
I tried: if(isset($_POST['name'])), But not result.

I was also looking for other options but could not get results.

I have a PHP code:

```
  <?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "..";
  $password = "..";
  $dbname = "..";

  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  $response = array();
  $posts = array();

  $sql = "SELECT name, addres, status, date  FROM silknet WHERE name='test'";

  $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
     $name=$row['name']; 
     $addres=$row['addres']; 
     $status=$row['status'];
     $date=$row['date'];

  $response[] = array('name'=> $name, 'addres'=> $addres, 'status'=>$status, 
  'date'=>$date);
  } 

  echo json_encode($response);
  ?>
```

Comment: Can you be more clear what you want to do actually.

Comment: The current code brings the array WHERE name = 'test' from the database, I want the name to be a variable and assign a name to any. name = 'test', 'test1', 'test2'. I do not want to write new PHP code for all names.

Comment: From what I understand you want to assign all names in database to 1 variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the top:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

And edit this line as:

```
 $sql = "SELECT name, addres, status, date  FROM silknet WHERE name='$name'";
```

Comment: I tried, but: Undefined array key "name", Here($name = $_POST['name'];)

Comment: Thanks, I was checking with the postman and running the function by mistake. The problem is solved.

Comment: @tornikekharitonishvili if my answer solved your problem, can you please accept it as solution?

Comment: How? I'm a beginner.

Comment: @tornikekharitonishvili you can click the check icon left of the answer.

Comment: ok, sezer iltekin